# Smarty modifier to add hyperlinks doesn't work when text is in parentheses

Tags: php, regex, smarty, modifier

I'm using a Smarty modifier to turn a plaintext link into a proper hyperlink, I'm using a Smarty modifier for this as it's for a website that utilizes user content, in which only some areas are allowed to have hyperlinks.

This is the modifier:

```
function smarty_modifier_dolink($text)
{
   $text = preg_replace('#(script|about|applet|activex|chrome):#is', "\\1:", $text);
   $ret = ' ' . $text;
   $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\">\\2</a>", $ret);
   $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\">\\2</a>", $ret);
   //$ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([a-z0-9&\-_.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+\.)*[\w]+)#i", "\\1<a href=\"mailto:\\2@\\3\">\\2@\\3</a>", $ret);
   $ret = substr($ret, 1);
   return $ret;
}
?>
```

The code for the modifier was shared on another website. It works fine but doesn't work when the plaintext link is in parentheses, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: http:// is insecure and not used widely anmore  - use https.   
https://regex101.com/isit https://regex101.com/  to learn more about Regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

One extracted PCRE regex:

```
(^|[\n ])\(?((www|ftp)\.[\w\#$%&~\/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)\)?
```

regex tested on [regex101.com](https://www.regex101.com)  with url
([www.example.com/test/test.html](http://www.example.com/test/test.html))

collection group2 -> [www.example.com/test/test.html](http://www.example.com/test/test.html)

So the following should work:

```
   $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])\(?((www|ftp)\.[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)\)?#is", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\">\\2</a>", $ret);
```

$ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])(?([\w]+?://[\w#$%&~/.-;:=,?@[]+]*)(?#is", "\1<a href="\2" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">\2", $ret);

Explanation: I have added

```
\)? 

/) for a bracket and ? for optional  at the positions where i suggested your brackets to be.
```